# Getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, exception

I'm trying to convert string type of a value in a dictionary to int type. I'm also using strip() function because the field value contains leading spaces. since the field contains few empty values I'm getting ValueError. I want to convert to int only for the values present in the column. If the value is empty I want the output to be "".

Below is the code where I'm trying to convert from string to int:

```
"user_rating": {
    "rating": int(row['RATING'].strip()) if 'RATING' in row else "           
}
```

output I'm expecting:

```
"user_rating": {
    "rating": 5
}
```

But getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/meghashree.r/PycharmProjects/populate_json/CSV_to_Json.py", line 72, in main
    "rating": int(row['RATING'].strip()) if 'RATING' in row else ""
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: you must have empty values for row['RATING'] -- check your data

Comment: yes there are few empty values as I have mentioned earlier

Comment: You only test for there being a `'RATING'` field. Not if there is one that is empty. In the latter case you try to run `int()` on an empty string, which is why you get the error.